# Rails: Post request to an action being routed to unintended action and throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here are my routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
  resources :agencies do
    member do
      get 'pdf'
    end
    collection do
      post 'index'
    end
end
```

When the user clicks the following link, I expect it to take them to `agencies#index`

```
    <%= link_to('Agencies List', agencies_path) %>
```

Instead of being processed in #index, it is being processed in #show.  When clicked, here is what is shown in the server log:

> Started GET "/agencies/index"
>
> Processing by AgenciesController#show as HTML
>
> Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}

When I remove `post 'index'` from the agencies routes, it does what is expected:

> Started GET "/agencies"
>
> Processing by AgenciesController#index as HTML

So clearly the issue is that I have `post 'index'`, but I am stumped on why this is happening.  I need a Post request to agencies#index for a form submission, and I also need a Get request to agencies#index for typical usage.

I am missing something fundamental about Rails Routing.  I did review [Rails Routing From the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but am still stumped.

**Update**  Here is the `rake routes` results:

```
agencies    POST   /agencies/index(.:format)        agencies#index
            GET    /agencies(.:format)              agencies#index
            POST   /agencies(.:format)              agencies#create
new_agency  GET    /agencies/new(.:format)          agencies#new
edit_agency GET    /agencies/:id/edit(.:format)     agencies#edit
agency      GET    /agencies/:id(.:format)          agencies#show
            PATCH  /agencies/:id(.:format)          agencies#update
            PUT    /agencies/:id(.:format)          agencies#update
            DELETE /agencies/:id(.:format)          agencies#destroy
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `rake routes` for agencies.

Comment: @Dusht added. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to post to `index`? Problem seems to be that the named route is assigned automatically to the route routing to `agencies#index` and in your case the POST route comes first, so the url is build incorrectly to hit the index action, and it will hit the show action with id index. So I am wondering why you need to post to `index`, to see how we can avoid that :)

Comment: @nathanvda the agencies#index page both lists all the agencies, and also provides a search form for the agencies.  That way the user can alter the search criteria to further condense their search if need be.  `GET agencies#index` is just a typical request that shows an empty form and lists all the agencies by default.  `POST agencies#index` is when the user submits a search.  The view shows the searched criteria and the resulting agencies matching that criteria.

Comment: Generally/semantically a search form is not considered a post, because you do not "change" data, you just hand down extra parameters (to filter/limit your result set). So just use GET for your search form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by making a change to the routes.rb file, but am still not sure why the above did not work as intended.  Anyways: this got it working as expected:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :agencies do
    member do
      get 'pdf'
    end
    collection do
      # Took out post `index` below
      # post 'index'
    end
  end
  post 'agencies/name_search', to: 'agencies#index'
end
```

And then I just had my search form point to `agencies_name_search_path`, and when I want to do a GET request to agencies#index I can do `agencies_path` as usual and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= link_to 'Agencies List', agencies_path, :method=> :post %>
```

Comment: I need the link to do the Get request to Agencies because I am not submitting the form here.  I am just doing a typical Get request to agencies#index.  However, adding that `post 'index'` makes it not work for some reason and routes it to agencies#show.  So doing the Post request for this link is not what I need it to do.  I need it to do the Get request to agencies#index.

Comment: Then you need to write `:method=> :get`

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working.  Specifying `method: :get` for the link is still making it route to agencies#show for some reason.

Comment: @Neil - routes for common CRUD actions for a resource are already provided by Rails, so index action route is agencies_path by default. So the link_to will work when you delete the route for index you wrote.

Comment: @AlokSwain the one I wrote is different in that it is a POST request and not a GET request.  I thought that the server would be abel to tell the difference, but I guess not?  I guess you can't have a GET and a POST request with the same action name?